# What is the logic performed by Get-ChildItem in the current scenario?

Tags: powershell

Can someone please explain to me the logic of the code "current version"?
In the C:\Program Files\ABC, there are multiple folders of ABC exe.
It is trying to get the most recent version, but I don't know how it works.
I want to translate this in C# ..  thank you Happy new year.

```
#SET CODE LINE
$codeline = 'ABC'
$path = 'C:\Program Files\ABC'

#set executable name for Task Agent
$exe = 'ABC.TaskAgent.exe'

#get the current version/release of ABC
$version = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Where-Object  { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match "$codeline\d+" } | Sort-Object { $_.Name } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Last 1
$app = "$path\$version\$exe"
Write-Output $app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recursively searching under the `$path` directory for all sub directories where the name matches `$codeline` with some following digits, it pipes that into a sort where the last item should be the latest version which is assigned to `$version` to be used in `$app`.